# Replace all instances of character between tags with vim

Tags: regex, vim, replace

I need to replace all instances of / character with \ between < filename >...< / filename > tags.

The file has like 2.000 of those tags and I only need to replace the / character inside those tags.

How can i do?

Comment: @ewok What makes this one different from the other hundreds of editor-related questions?

Comment: @ewok: it's been pretty well established that vim questions (particualrly regex questions like this) fall squarely in the "software tools commonly used by programmers" category explicitly listed as "on topic" in the faq

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Edit:  Given the new information, the below substitution would probably work:

```
:%s/<filename>\zs.\{-}\ze<\/filename>/\=substitute(submatch(0), '\/', '\', 'g')/
```

Explaination:

- `%s`: substitute across the entire file
- `/<filename>`: start of pattern and static text to match against
- `\zs`: start of the matched text
- `.\{-}`: any character, non greedy
- `\ze`: end of matched text
- `<\/filename>/`: end of targeted tag and pattern
- `\=`: evaluate the replacement as a vim expression
- `substitute(submatch(0), '\/', '\', 'g')/`: replace all `/`'s with `\` in the matched text.

---

Original answer:

I'm going to assume you mean XML-style tags here.  What I would do is visually select the area you'd like to operate on, then use the `\%V` regex atom to only operate on that selection.

```
vit:s!\%V/!\\!g
```

Should do the trick.  Note that when pressing `:`, vim will automatically add a range for the visual selection, the actual substitution command will look like:

```
:'<,'>s!\%V/!\\!g
```

Comment: Thanks, but this only works on the actual tag selected, not in all the tags, do it?

Comment: Correct.  That is a detail you may want to make a little more obvious in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Iff we can assume that the  tags are on single lines, it is simply:

<sub>**Note** Enter `^M` as <kbd>C-v</kbd><kbd>C-m</kbd> (*<kbd>C-q</kbd><kbd>C-m</kbd> on windows*)</sub>

```
:g/<filename>/norm! /filename>/e^Mvity:let @"=substitute(@", '/', '\\', "g")^Mgvp
```

Hmmm integrating the hint by Randy on using \%V in a pattern makes it simpler:

```
:g/<filename>/norm! /filename>/e^Mvit:s#\%V/#\\#g^M
```

I tested both. Whoo. I'll explain now. Hold on.

1. `:g/<filename>/` - _for each line containing `<filename>`
2. `norm!` - _execute normal commands (ignoring mappings)
3. `/filename/e`<sub><sup><kbd>Enter</kbd></sup></sub> *jump to the end of the open tag*
4. `vit` - *select the inner text of that tag in visual mode*
5. `:s#\%V/#\\#g`<sub><sup><kbd>Enter</kbd></sup></sub> - _on that visual selection, perform the substitution (replace `\` by `/`)

Answer (score 0):

VIM has a sharp learning curve, as do regex's.  I believe this command will do it.  You have to escape each char with '\'.

```
:%s/\//\\/g
```

Comment: Thanks, but this will replace more / than I need to replace, I only need to replace the / inside < filename > ... < / filename >

Comment: Oh, my bad, you just want to switch paths in the tags.  I don't know the regex off the top of my head; try checking out this tutorial: http://www.thatsquality.com/articles/how-to-match-and-replace-content-between-two-html-tags-using-regular-expressions